# Cron job error for php file

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, phpmailer, cron

I'm developing an app that should runs once a day a PHP script for sending mail and SMS.

I'm new to use cron jobs, i've set correctly the crontab, the PHP file is running but I receive this **error**:

```
/srv/applicazioni/shuttle/server/mylac.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/srv/applicazioni/shuttle/server/mylac.php: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `'/data/applicazioni/shuttle/server/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/''
/srv/applicazioni/shuttle/server/mylac.php: line 2: `set_include_path('/data/app'icazioni/shuttle/server/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/');
```

This is the point in the script that I receive the error:

```
<?php 
set_include_path('/data/applicazioni/shuttle/server/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/');
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
?>
```

The file `PHPMailerAutoload.php` on the server is in `/data/applicazioni/shuttle/server/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/`

How can i solve it?

Thank's

Comment: in cron file path of any external file is put to be absolute not relative. So make sure your path are correct

Comment: I've used the command readlink for getting the path of the file and it returns /data/applicazioni/shuttle/server/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php @MASIDDIQUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron scripts are expected to be shell scripts, and `<` is a redirect operator in a shell, so when you say:

```
<?php
```

that's saying "get input from a file called `?php`", which of course doesn't exist, so you get `?php: No such file or directory`. You need to add a "hashbang" to the start of your file to tell it to run the script using the PHP interpreter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
...
```

Comment: Thank's, i've modified the script in this way but I've received this error: : No such file or directory

Comment: this is my crontab: 49 10 * * *  /data/applicazioni/shuttle/server/mylac.php

Comment: This sounds like your PHP env isn't set up right. Does it work if you run the PHP script manually with `/usr/bin/php /data/applicazioni/shuttle/server/mylac.php`?

Comment: Now i've received this: /bin/sh: usr/bin/php: No such file or directory